# How to disable" "new message from" from popping up in Thunderbird (on a mac mini)

Tags: thunderbird

Whenever I get an incoming email in Thunderbird, a box pops up at the corner of my screen saying "...new message from..."

The box sits over the icon to delete the message. I cannot close the box.  So, if I want to delete the message, I have to wait until the box closes.

What can I do to stop the message from appearing or to close the box sooner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On newer releases of macOS, the alert configuration is done via *System Preferences* *>* *Notifications* rather than within Thunderbird itself. See the screenshot below - disabling *Banners* and *Alerts* should stop the popups from appearing.

[image: Thunderbird Notification preferences]

Comment: Changing from Banners to Alerts did it for me.  With Alerts I can click on Close.  So now I get the alert but do not have to wait for it to disappear on its own.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Windows but most probably the settings is in the same place: go to `Tools -> Options -> General` and disable `When new messages arrive... Show an alert`. In `Customize` there's also an option for setting the display period.

Edit: On macOS, this seems to be in `Thunderbird -> Preferences -> General -> When new messages arrive` uncheck: `Show an alert`

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1164389

Comment: I do not see an option like that on my mac mini.  I looked here: Thunderbird Preferences.

Comment: Is that Thunderbird 52.5?

Comment: Yes, version 52.5.0